# Origin of phrase `computational microscope'

Tags: reference-request, terminology

I have heard the term 'computational microscope' used to describe the practice of molecular simulation (in the context e.g. computational chemistry, materials science) and its use as a numerical tool for predicting scientific properties of materials, etc. I have also heard 'numerical microscope' in the same context.

Is there a well-known origin for this terminology / expression? References would be ideal.

Comment: Interesting question. I do particle-based simulation and never heard either expression before. In what context have you seen it used?

Comment: @lr1985 I have certainly seen it in the first section of this book (https://cermics.enpc.fr/~lelievre/free_energy_book.html). I have somehow managed to convince myself that I have also heard the phrase elsewhere, but it's possible that my mind is playing tricks on me.

Comment: This question would also probably fit on the new Materials Modeling SE if you don't find an answer here

Comment: @Tyberius thank you for the heads up, I will keep that in mind.